# how to convert list to json and pass in rest client url

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I implemented an application using spring and restful web services.  Here I convert list into json format and try to pass in client url, but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 142: http://10.248.84.132:8082/nppWebService/updateModelGPData.do?lgdCode=33589&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={"noOfTrainingsOrganized":2,"noOfErsParticipated":4,"noOfOfficialsParticipated":5}
    at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.resource(Client.java:433)
    at com.org.ep.trg.webservice.ClientRestController.main(ClientRestController.java:21)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 142: http://10.248.84.132:8082/nppWebService/updateModelGPData.do?lgdCode=33589&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={"noOfTrainingsOrganized":2,"noOfErsParticipated":4,"noOfOfficialsParticipated":5}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Here is my method:

```
List<ModelGPStatusEntity>list2=new ArrayList<ModelGPStatusEntity>();
list2.add(new ModelGPStatusEntity(2,4,5));
String gson=new Gson().toJson(list2);
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(
            "http://10.248.84.132:8082/nppWebService/updateModelGPData.do?lgdCode=33589&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData="+gson.replace("[","").replace("]",""));

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}

String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
System.out.println(output);
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it the right approach to pass a json data in url and if it is wrong what is the best way to pass json and call the client url.
2. if it is correct how to solve this exception

Comment: You could use a POST method and put whole JSON as string into request

Comment: You probably want to encode the json (i.e. { should be replaced with %7B). The other option is to pass the contant of json data as query params or if you are actually sending data to your service, use the POST operation and send it in the request's payload

Answer (score 1):

You are passing characters that are illegal for an URI when calling client.resource(). In particular, the unescaped double-quotes will be probably the cause.

Try using [UriBuilder](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) to create valid URI with problematic characters escaped.

Alternatively, most of the REST web services should be able to accept POST with the JSON data in the body of the request instead of part of the URL.